# Mistake in custom implementation of printf

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement my own version of printf and I'm having trouble when I need to print an argument of the form `%pd`, where p is the number of characters to be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(char *, ...);
char *convert(unsigned int, int);
char *to_lower(unsigned int, int);
unsigned int count_digits(unsigned int);

int main()
{
    char str[12]="World";
    char c='A';
    int n = 5, x= 1011, y = 12, z = 5, t = 10;

    print("Hello s c |%s| |%c| 5 |%d| 5 some random %X %x %b %o words\n", str, c, n, x, y, z, t);
    print("%5d\n", y);

}

void print(char *format, ...)
{
    int num, precision = 0, nDigits, i, temp;
    char *num_deca;

    va_list lst;
    va_start(lst, format);

    while(*format != '\0')
    {
        if(*format != '%')
        {
            putchar(*format);
            format++;
            continue;
        }

        format++;

        if(isdigit(*format))
        {
            temp = atoi(format);
            precision = precision*10+temp;
            //precision = atoi(format);
            format++;
            continue;
        }
//      format++;

        switch(*format)
        {
            case 'c':
                putchar(va_arg(lst, int)); 
                break;
            case 'd':
                num = (va_arg(lst, int));
                //nDigits = count_digits(num);

                if(num > 0)
                {
                    num_deca = convert(num, 10);
                    nDigits = count_digits(num);
                    for(i = 0; i < (precision - nDigits); i++)
                    {
                        putchar(' ');
                    }
                    fputs(num_deca, stdout);

                   // fputs(convert(num,10), stdout);
                }
                else
                {
                    num = -num;
                    putchar('-');
                    fputs(convert(num,10), stdout);
                }
                break;
            case 's':
                fputs(va_arg(lst, char *), stdout);
                break;
            case 'X':
                num = va_arg(lst, int);
                fputs(convert(num,16), stdout);
                break;
            case 'x':
                num = va_arg(lst, int);
                fputs(to_lower(num,16), stdout);
                break;
            case 'b':
                num = va_arg(lst, int);
                fputs(convert(num,2), stdout);
                break;
            case 'o':
                num = va_arg(lst, int);
                fputs(convert(num,8), stdout);
                break;
        }

        format++;
    }

    va_end(lst);
}

char *convert(unsigned int num, int base) 
{ 
    static char Representation[]= "0123456789ABCDEF";
    static char buffer[50]; 
    char *ptr; 

    ptr = &buffer[49]; 
    *ptr = '\0'; 

    do 
    { 
        *--ptr = Representation[num%base]; 
        num /= base; 
    }while(num != 0); 

    return(ptr); 
}

char *to_lower(unsigned int num, int base) 
{
    static char Representation[]= "0123456789abcdef";
    static char buffer[50];
    char *ptr;

    ptr = &buffer[49];
    *ptr = '\0';

    do
    {
        *--ptr = Representation[num%base]; 
        num /= base; 
    }while(num != 0); 

    return(ptr); 
}

unsigned int count_digits(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    while(n != 0)
    {
        n = n/10;
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

```
Output: Hello s c |World| |A| 5 |5| 5 some random 3F3 c 101 12 words
d
```

So, the basic cases are working fine, the only issue I'm encountering is on the second print. The number 12 with `%5d%` should be whitespacewhitespacewhitespace12 (since 12 only has 2 digits). I computed the number of digits of the argument and used a for loop that goes until the difference between the precision and the number of digits, but then the program doesn't consider d as being part of the format specifier anymore and just prints the letter 'd'. Any idea why?

Comment: `if(isdigit(*format)) { ..continue; }` That's the problem. `continue` causes the loop to start again. The next character is a `d` and not a `%`. Suggest you remove the `continue`.

Comment: May I suggest that you use a debugger if you have not already done so. It allows you to step thru your code line by line. If you do that you should be able to easily see where the code goes wrong. Learning to use the debugger is an essential dev skill and will save you lots of time.

Comment: Aside: `count_digits(0)` returns 0.  Certianly1 is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you print every character until you find a '%'. If you find a '%' you go to the next character and process it. However, if the next character is a digit, you modify precission and make a 'continue' to the start of the loop. When re-starting the loop, the next character (a 'd') is not a '%', so it just get printed as is. You should have a variable that tells you if you are still processing a sequence, or either don't go to the start of the loop before you end the processing of the full sequence ('%5d').